# Has there ever arisen a nation-state without violence/war/extreme subordination?

Tags: international-relations, nationalism

Has there ever arisen a nation-state (building/birth/creation of a new nation state) without violence/war/extreme subordination? But rather peacefully, organically, with all parties and neighbours being enthusiastic?

Answer (score -2):

There are many examples.  Here are just two, wildly different:

[Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Canada):

> Although responsible government had existed in Canada since 1848, Britain continued to set its foreign and defence policies until the end of the First World War. The passing of the Statute of Westminster in 1931 recognized that Canada had become co-equal with the United Kingdom. After the Constitution was patriated in 1982, the final vestiges of legal dependence on the British parliament were removed.

[Nauru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauru):

> Nauru became self-governing in January 1966, and following a two-year constitutional convention, it became independent in 1968 ...

Then there are countries such as China, Thailand, and Iran (and others) that have been independent, sovereign nations for centuries.  At what exact moment did China, for example, become a "nation-state"?

Comment: Canada has itself even essentially admitted that it was built on genocide: https://www.mmiwg-ffada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Supplementary-Report_Genocide.pdf

Comment: Its a bit of a stretch to describe an imperial possession as being "without violence/war/extreme subordination". Sure the last chapter might look like that, but only if you ignore everything that went before.